# showing that two curves intersect at 90 degrees

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = 2x^2 + y^2 $ and $g(x) = \frac{y^2}{x} $

By looking at the level curves of $f= C $ and $g = C$, we see that these curves intersect orthogonally. Is there a way to prove this ?

Answer (score 0):

Angle between two curves is given by $$\tan \theta =\frac{f_xg_y-g_xf_y}{f_xg_x+f_yg_y}$$Here , $f_xg_x+f_yg_y=0$. So, $\tan \theta=\infty$ implies $\theta=90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Can we also argue that if $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g = 0 $ ,then they intersect orthogonally?